# Scraping a webpage that uses ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to webscrape data from an Indian Government [Public Data Portal](http://nregarep2.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic2/dynamicreport_new4.aspx). First I need to submit a form to get the data. [image]

In the picture above you can see the screenshot of the form. The form allows you to choose states within India, districts within states, blocks within districts and panchayats within blocks. In the figure above, Andaman and Nicobar is a state, Nicobar is a district, Campbell Bay is a block and Govindnagar is a panchayat.

I need to collect data of all panchayats. The form data that is sent while submitting the form contains the value of the checkboxes of all the panchayat that have been selected. There are more than 250,000 panchayats and it is almost impossible to do it manually. So, I used beautifulsoup to parse the html elements of the form to get the value of the checkboxes of all the panchayat. But the information about panchayat level is not loaded when the page is loaded. The page perform a ajax post at http://nregarep2.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic2/DynamicReport_new4.aspx/getGPs when each block is expanded. It gets the information about panchayat and then renders it to the page.

Now, I am trying to simulate the ajax post to obtain the information about panchayats but I am getting an error. The figure below shows the network activity. [image]

My code:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
request_headers = {
    'Host': 'nregarep2.nic.in',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '46',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Origin': 'http://nregarep2.nic.in',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Referer': 'http://nregarep2.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic2/dynamicreport_new4.aspx',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

payload = {'state_code':'01', 'block_code':'0102003', 'year':'2013'}

getGPs = s.post('http://nregarep2.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic2/DynamicReport_new4.aspx/getGPs', data=payload, headers = request_headers)

print(getGPs.text)
```

I get:

```
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}
```

I have changed request_headers with various combinations of the items that are present in the request headers with no luck.

Comment: Don't you missed cookies? Try to «Copy as cURL» option in networks tab of developer tools of you browser (like Chrome).

Comment: Use a headless browser to render page and let the ajax populate it

Comment: Hey @spacediver, my understanding was that sessions handles that. Anyway, I tried but still get the same message. charlietfl, Let me try it.

Comment: Sometimes it's crucial to reconstruct every bit of request. Try copying as cURL and actually executing this request in your console. Would you get desired result? You should. Then translate that curl line into python. This would give you most accurate reconstruction of what browser does (without heavylifting of actual browser, as @charlietfl suggested quite rightly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a little in your existing script to get the response. Try `data=json.dumps(payload)` instead of `data=payload`like below:

```
import json
payload = {'state_code':'01', 'block_code':'0102003', 'year':'2013'}

getGPs = s.post('http://nregarep2.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic2/DynamicReport_new4.aspx/getGPs', data=json.dumps(payload), headers = request_headers)

#notice the payload parameter in the post request
```

It produces the below result:

```
{"d":"{\"0102003001\":\"GOVINDNAGAR\",\"0102003002\":\"CAMPBELL BAY\",\"0102003003\":\"LAXMI NAGAR\",\"0102003004\":\"Great & Little Nicobar\"}"}
```

Comment: Did you try this script? What's your feedback @krish?

Comment: Hi @Shahin. Just woke up :D. Great, it works. Thank you.